# Ruby next multiple

Tags: ruby, loops

Is there another way to write `'a'.next.next`? I've looked all over and can't seem to find it.

I've tried multiplying the `.next` but I keep getting errors.

Comment: I just tried using `.next.next` and it worked -- what error are you getting?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. .next.next works fine. I just need to know if there is another way of writing it, like if I needed to use next 20 times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, this *might* not be a good idea in the case here, but if you're looking to chain a method *n* times in general, you can do something like this:

```
2.times.inject('a') { |s| s.next }
# => 'c'

20.times.inject('a') { |s| s.next }
# => 'u'
```

This starts with the value `'a'`, runs a block that calls `next`, then each successive result is fed back into the block.

For what it's worth, monkey-patching `String` can be fine for trivial scripts, but personally I'd try to look for other solutions first, like just adding a utility function to your class/module:

```
def repeat_next(str, n = 1)
  n.times.inject(str) { |s| s.next }
end
```

A shortcut for your specific problem, `(a.ord + 2).chr`, potentially exists, although it's [not the same thing](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-next).

Comment: I like `.inject` solution better. It's a pity `2.times.inject('a', &:next)` doesn't work.

Comment: @jaeheung I agree totally. Unfortunately, it fails because it attempts to pass the index generated by `times` to `String#next`, which is an error because `String#next` accepts no arguments. That is, what you wrote is equivalent to `2.times.inject('a') { |s, i| s.next i }`.

Answer (score 3):

You can just redefine `String.next` like this:

```
class String
  alias_method :next1, :next
  def next(n = 1)
    str = self
    for i in 1..n
      str = str.next1
    end
    str
  end
end

puts 'a'.next
puts 'a'.next(2)
puts 'a'.next(20)
```

Comment: This seems the most sensible - it's a very clean extension of existing  methods with no surprises.

Comment: I'd go with the `inject` based answer. As monkey-patches go this is on the more reasonable side but my experience is that monkey-patching core classes isn't a solution that ages well if you expect the code to live long.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a more succinct way of doing this, you could use: `('a'.ord + 2).chr`. This will convert 'a' to a numerical representation (with the "ord" method), increment it by two, then converts it back to the character representation (with "chr").

Comment: The behavior is not the same. 'z'.next returns "aa", while ('z'.ord + 2).chr returns "|".

Comment: That is problematic. I'm going to leave the answer for now though, since this may still be useful depending on what the OP is trying to accomplish (I'll just take it down if he says it isn't though).

Comment: Thank you @Bubbles, that is helpful and it worked great with a pre-defined array. Thank you for posting. But jeaheung's answer is more what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can monkey-patch the `String` class in ruby to add a method to do this for you:

```
class String
    def get_nth_char(n)
      current = self
      while n > 0 do
        current = current.next
        n = n - 1
      end

      current
    end
end
```

So you can do `'a'.get_nth_char(2) # => 'c'`

Comment: When you provide an answer like this it is helpful to show usage.